# Why is the next build command failing to prerender my page?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a really simple page set up using Next `13.4.19`. I'm using app directory and have a page.tsx file in the root of the `app`-folder, like so:

```
app/
 ├─ globals.css
 ├─ layout.tsx
 ├─ page.module.css
 ├─ page.tsx
```

The contents are the following:

```js
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The error says the following:

```
- info Creating an optimized production build ...
Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

...

> Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /page: /
```

The prerender error link provided in the error is not particularly helpful, and seems to believe that I'm not running Next 13 and using `pages` directory routing. Maybe there is something wrong with my Next configuration that attempts a build with an incorrect Next version?

Other similar posts on SO seems to be using older Next versions with `pages` directories. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a `layout.tsx` file in the app root folder? Otherwise LGTM. It shouldn't give you an error.

Comment: Yes, I have a `layout.tsx` at the same level. Updated the folder structure

Comment: Try to create another project with `npx create-next-app@latest` and compare it to where did you wrong or changed with configuration. I'm surprised that you got this error. Typically, I get to see it when a specific page needs to be dynamic instead of prerendering.